# CMS with other backend

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, content-management-system

I am very new to CMS technology.
My problem is that, I have a new project required a CMS to manage all the content.
It also requires some function in my other Spring boot backend server.
Can CMS integrate with another Spring boot server?
Or is CMS allow to add some code and do the same job as Spring boot server?
Any recommend CMS can do the above task?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the community project [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This project adds industry standard CMS functionality to Spring using a similar programming model to Spring Data.

It allows you to quickly and easily create Spring Boot-based content management services built with components of your choice.  Storage options include the filesystem, database, s3 or mongo's grid fs.  Also supports fulltext indexing and search (via solr or elasticsearch), rendition and locking and versioning.

Integrates easily with Spring Boot, Spring Data and Spring Security.

You can get a good idea of how it works from this [introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).